# Embed Google My Business Review without showing address?

Tags: google-plus, embed, google-my-business-api

Currently you can share a Google review on your Google+ page and then from there you can embed the google review using their embed code on to your website. This is nice, but it shows a lot of information.

I was curious if there is any way to modify what information is shown in the embedded Google review box?

Here is a link to a page with Google reviews embeded.
[Page With Good Reviews Embeded](https://www.penair.com.au/about/google-reviews/)

As you can see it shows the address of the company in every review right above the rating star icons.

All I'd like to do is the same thing only without the address. Is this possible?